# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Use the `initWithVideoIdentifier:` method instead

Tags: ios, youtube, ios8

Hi in my application I'm playing youtube video inside my application using `XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController` its working fine in IOS 7 but its showing error in IOS 8 like.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Use the `initWithVideoIdentifier:` method instead
```

Then i have searched for solution then i got this link [click here](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/issues/69) i did excalty like they mention i have installed the latest verion of  XCDYouTubeKit 2.0.2 using `Cocoapods` the problem and the i have imported that library in .h file.

```
#import <XCDYouTubeKit/XCDYouTubeKit.h>
```

i have did code like this.

```
  XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:@"9bZkp7q19f0"];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
    [videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
```

but it still showing same error please can some please help me with this have stuck here for long time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make 100% sure you are using the latest version of XCDYouTubeKit (2.0.3 as of this writing). The issue you describe only exists in version 1.x.